# Unable tu mount 1.0 TB Volume

Tags: mount

When I connect mey Samsung S2 Portable 3 HDD, i get following message:

```
Unable to Mount 1.0 TB Volume
error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/Reding/
d45c6601-557e-4dbac-9ec8-247b68491a70: Commane-line `mount-t
"xfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,node,nosuid" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/hreding/
d45c6601-557e-4bac-9ec8-247b68491a70" exited with non-Zero Exit
status32: Mount:mount/dev/sdb1 on/media/hreding/
d45c6601-557e-4bac-9ec8-247b68491a70 failed: No data avalaible.
```

what can I do to get Access to the files on this HDD?

Thanks for any help

hreding

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog or `dmesg` for more detailed errors.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal window :

1. First create a directory, to which you are going to mount your HDD.

sudo mkdir -p /media/Name_of_directory

eg : mkdir -p /media/storage

2. Run the below command to get the volume_id

   fdisk -l |grep GB

   Disk /dev/xvda1: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes

   Disk /dev/xvdk: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes

   **Disk /dev/xvdn: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes**

Note down the volume id for your 1 TB volume ,

In this case :/dev/xvdn is the volume having 1TB

3. Then mount the volume ( /dev/xvdn ) to the created directory,

sudo mount /dev/xvdn /media/storage

4. Now run df -h will list all your volumes, connected to the system,

You can access your files using, cd /media/storage.